# M4 not expanding all macros in .m4 file

Tags: linux, m4, i3

I'm using `m4` to replace some macros with colors/etc defined in included files in my `i3wm` config file.

```
$ m4 -I themes/gruvbox-dark config.m4 > config
```

This is (an excerpt of) my directory structure for the above command.

```
$ tree .
.
├── config.m4
├── font.m4
├── themes
│   ├── gruvbox-dark
│   │   ├── color.m4
│   │   └── i3.m4
└── Xresources.m4
```

I have macros defined such as:

```
define(M4_COLOR_FG,`#a89984')
define(M4_I3_FG,`M4_COLOR_FG')
define(M4_I3_BG,`#3c3836')
```

and in the output of `m4` I still see unexpanded macros, such as:

```
client.focused #3c3836 M4_I3_BG M4_I3_ACTIVE_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.focused_inactive #3c3836 M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.unfocused #3c3836 M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.urgent #fb4934 M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_9 M4_COLOR_9 M4_I3_BG
client.placeholder #3c3836 M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.background #282828
```

The first macro was expanded, but the remaining ones on the line are left unexpanded. Here are the same lines in the input .m4 file:

```
client.focused M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_ACTIVE_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.focused_inactive M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.unfocused M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.urgent M4_COLOR_9 M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_9 M4_COLOR_9 M4_I3_BG
client.placeholder M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG M4_COLOR_FG M4_I3_BG M4_I3_BG
client.background M4_COLOR_BG
```

When I try to make some MWEs, it always works... not sure what the problem is with these specific files/macros.

All the files are under: https://github.com/tomocafe/dotfiles/tree/master/i3/.i3

I have tried this at work and at home, my home computer is Solus (Linux).

```
$ m4 --version | head -1
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple: if you want expand the `M4_COLOR_3 M4_COLOR_3`:

1. `m4` replace the first `M4_COLOR_3` to `#colorcode`.
2. `m4` doesn't expand the next `M4_COLOR_3` because the (expanded) `#` means comment.

You've the solution:

1. You'll change (or disable) the comment character with `changecom`.
2. You'll use double quotation inside definition: *define(FOO,``#aabbcc'')*

The first: `changecom(XXX)` will change the comment begin mark (only in `m4` of course) to `XXX` and the end will the newline. The `changecom()' will disable the comments (so everything will parsed by`m4`).

The second:

```
define(FOO,``#aabbcc'')
FOO FOO FOO FOO FOO
```